# Button disappearing in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Could you please advise how can I style my divs, so they are displayed next to each other in two rows? I have few items in html and three of them are `.card1` and the other `.card2`, `.service` is for the whole container. I wish the divs are placed next to each other in two lines. Could you please help me in styling them? :)

```css
.service {
  background: #08122f;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.card1 {
  height: 365px;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background: #251f4a;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.card2 {
  height: 365px;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background: #251f4a;
  display: flex-start;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I create for you a snippet with your css, please post your html too.

Comment: @Simone Rossaini - Don't create interactive snippets when the code is not runnable. This should be a code block, and not a stack snippet. See: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/979052)

Comment: _please post your html too_ What do you not understand about this sentence?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
display: inline flow-root list-item;
```

Example:

```css
.service {
  background: #08122f;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.card1 {
  height: 365px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background: #251f4a;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline flow-root list-item;
}

.card2 {
  height: 365px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background: #251f4a;
  display: flex-start;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline flow-root list-item;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
    <div class="card1"></div>
    <div class="card1"></div>
    <div class="card1"></div>
    <div class="card2"></div>
</div>
```